# Difference between u8, uint8_t, __u8 and __be8

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

While browsing linux networking code, I came across these datatypes:

> 1. u8
> 2. uint8_t
> 3. __u8
> 4. __be8

(same things for 16, 32 and 64 bits)

Can someone please explain the difference between these datatypes and where to use which?
I have seen the definitions of these datatypes but those were not clear to me.

Comment: The last denotes big-endian (Not significant for a single byte), aka network-byte-order, the others are all identical to each other, an unsigned type of 8 bits / 1 byte.

Comment: You should usually only use `uint8_t` out of that list; for portabilities sake.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`uint8_t` is Standard C and represents an unsigned 8-bit integral type. If you are on a system that does not have 8-bit addressable units then this will not be defined; otherwise it is probably a `typedef` for `unsigned char`.

Anything with `__` in it is reserved for implementation use. This means that compiler writers and standard library writers can use those identifiers without worrying about a name clash with user code. You may see this when looking in the internals of standard library implementation.

`u8` is non-standard but almost certainly means the same as `uint8_t`.  A reason that `u8` might be used is in code that was written before `uint8_t` was added to Standard C.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention u_int8_t. What is the use of this?

Comment: @Soumen take a wild guess

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Same as uint8_t?

Comment: @Sourmen Yeah, it's a common naming convention (`u` for unsigned)

Comment: Caveat: Since C++11, `u8` is used for [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).

Comment: @Hermann That usage only applies if immediately followed by an opening `"` though, so it is distinct from using `u8` as a type name in a declaration

Answer (score 1):

The last denotes big-endian (Not significant for a single byte), aka network-byte-order.

The others are all identical to each other, an unsigned type of 8 bits / 1 byte.

The above all holds for those types with 16 bits / 2 byte resp. 32 bits / 4 bytes too.

(Host byte-order on x86 for example is little-endian, and Linux only runs on 8-bit-byte machines.)

Out of the list only `uint8_t` is defined by the C standard (in `<stdint.h`), and the last two are in the implementations name-space, which is generally a bad idea.

Comment: The last one is probably identical too, just a naming convention for better keeping track of variables.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: As I said, not significant for the single-byte-case.

Answer (score 0):

@Soumen

> "Sorry I forgot to mention u_int8_t. What is the use of this?"

what `uint8_t` is for windows, `u_int8_t`  is for linux. 
For windows, when using `uint8_t`, the header file `<stdint.h>`  must be used. 
if you are bringing the code from linux to windows environment, maybe it is better to change to `uint8_t`  format.
source: [https://www.binarytides.com/data-type-u_int8_t-u_int16_t-u_int32_t-on-windows/][1]